# How to inherit namespaces in c++

Tags: c++, oop, namespaces

I have a few classes in my project that I would like to wrap into a namespace. I am using inheritance to make some child classes inherit properties from the parent.

I am wondering what the correct way is to define a namespace for the child classes. I tried declaring my parent class as:

```
namespace myNamespace {
    class A {
        ... 
    };
}
```

And then in the child class:

```
class B : public A {
    ...
};
```

However this does not seem to put class `B` in the same namespace as `A` (myNamespace ).

Comment: `namespace myNamespace { class B : public A { }; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not smart trick to do that. Namespaces are completely unrelated to classes or inheritance concept.

You should declare `B` in namespace as usual:

```
namespace myNamespace {
    class B : public A {
    ...
    };
}
```

Or put `B` definiton in the same block as `A` (if they are defined in the same file)

```
namespace myNamespace {
    class A {
        ... 
    };

    class B : public A {
        ...
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** *inherith* namespace. There is not such a feature in `C++`.

What you can and **should** do is simply wrap your child class definition in the same namespace of your parent class as in the following:

```
namespace myNamespace { //same namespace of A
    class B : public A {

    };
}
```